# creating a hover action on mouseover that triggers element inside div

Tags: jquery

If I have a set of 2 divs that are next to each other:

```
            <div class="selector outdoor">
            <div class="bar">
              <a href="#" class="firstOne"><p>Outdoor</p></a>
            </div><!--end of "bar"-->
        </div><!--end of "selector outdoor"-->
        <div class="selector hunter">
            <div class="bar">
              <a href="#" class="firstOne"><p>Hunting</p></a>
            </div><!--end of "bar"-->
        </div><!--end of "selector hunter"-->
        <div class="selector military">
```

If i want to create a hover action when i mouseover .selector, that triggers only the .bar inside of the div i am hovering over what would my jquery look like? Here's what I have.

```
$('.selector').hover(function ()  {
    TweenMax.to(this('.bar'), 1, {y:"-154px", ease:Power1.easeInOut});

});
$('.selector').mouseleave(function ()  {
    TweenMax.to(this('.bar'), 1, {y:"0", ease:Power1.easeInOut});
});
```

I know i can use "this to trigger the object with mouse focus, but i don't know how to use children selectors to move only the one inside of the parent div.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).find('.bar')
```

will select only the `'.bar'` element(s) inside the current element.

I'm not familiar with `TweenMax`, but I assume you'd end up with code like this:

```
$('.selector').hover(function ()  {
    TweenMax.to($(this).find('.bar'), 1, {y:"-154px", ease:Power1.easeInOut});
});
```

If the `TweenMax.to()` function is expecting a DOM element in that first parameter rather than a jQuery object then use `$(this).find('.bar').get(0)`.

Note also that `.hover()` and `mouseleave()` are not opposites. If you supply a single function to `.hover()` it will be executed on *both* mouseenter and mouseleave. To do something different on enter and leave supply two functions to `.hover()` (and don't call `mouseleave()` at all):

```
$('.selector').hover(function ()  {
    TweenMax.to($(this).find('.bar'), 1, {y:"-154px", ease:Power1.easeInOut});
},function ()  {
    TweenMax.to($(this).find('.bar'), 1, {y:"0", ease:Power1.easeInOut});
});
```

Or use `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` but not `.hover()`.